# XUL panel css styling firefox sdk

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon-sdk

So I created a panel in main.js using this code:

```
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var panel = win.document.createElement('panel');
var screen = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.screen;
var props = {
   noautohide: true,
   noautofocus: false,
   backdrag: true,
   level: 'top',
   style: 'padding:10px; margin:0; width:530px; height:90px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); border:none;'
}
for (let p in props) {
   panel.setAttribute(p, props[p]);
}
win.document.querySelector('#mainPopupSet').appendChild(panel);

panel.openPopup(null, 'overlap', screen.availLeft+screen.width/2-256, screen.availTop+760);
```

I don't really understand how it works but it seems to be the only way to make a panel transparent. My issue is I want to style this panel and its content so I tried this:

```
var panelStyle = win.document.createElement('link');
panelStyle.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
panelStyle.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
panelStyle.setAttribute('href', 'custom_panel.css');
panel.appendChild(panelStyle);
```

custom_panel.css being in the data folder but it doesn't seem to work.

**Update 1:**
Following Druzion advice I created p as such:

```
var p = win.document.createElement('p');
panel.appendChild(p);
```

and custom_panel.css is:

```
p
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

but the css does not seem to take effect.

Comment: It may be because `<src>` is not a HTML tag. You probably want `<link>`. Try changing this, `win.document.createElement('src')`, to this, `win.document.createElement('link');`

Comment: I changed 'src' to 'link' and added a textarea to the panel but the textarea doesn't seem to be affected by "custom_panel.css".

Comment: I would suggest using a `<p>` with a custom background color - That is the simplest way to test CSS. Also, you should consider updating the code in the question to `link`.

Comment: Any idea if this is even possible? I don't see anything about it in the docs even though this is not the recommended way to make a panel.

Comment: Well, you are definitely not meant to use XUL if you are using the SDK, so it is not really supported. However, the panel would be created this way if you are creating a bootstrapped add-on, so I think it will be possible... I will fiddle around with the code and see if I can get it to work, if not, good luck! I would certainly like to see this work!

Comment: There is a way to style panel content by embedding an iframe and setAttribute('src', 'ressource://addon-id@jetpack/data/custom_panel.html') but I don't know how to access the '.html' content from main.js.(maybe a custom worker).

Comment: One more thing, try `('href', './custom_panel.css')` instead of `('href', 'custom_panel.css')`, Use the `./`. See if that works

Comment: Already tried that. How could I see if the '.css' is loaded?

Comment: There may be an add-on to inspect the panel. I know there is a DOM inspector in Thunderbird (so you can refer to the XUL for the main window when making themes)

Comment: I tried your code, it does not seem to work - No panel is created (at least I cannot see it). I copied your code exactly (from the first block). Also, I am not getting any errors

Comment: You need to use the panel.openPopup function, I added the function in the first post at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107107/discussion-between-druzion-and-2a-66-42).